# How do you run Quarkus tests in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, quarkus, kaniko

I’m very new to Quarkus and I’m trying to get images of Quarkus services building via kaniko in a k8s pipeline, but when the tests try to fire up the DockerTestContainers, the kaniko image has no Docker machine installed.

The k8s cluster also does not have Docker available which means I can’t execute the maven wrapper to build the Jar on a jenkins worker node.

So far I’ve tried putting Java and Kaniko into one image to see if I could leverage build tools inside kaniko to build the test container, but no luck.

As k8s doesn’t support Docker anymore, what is the best way forward here?

EDIT: As DevServices are raising a DB for integration tests in this process, I’m thinking the best approach is to create a DB pod and point the Quarkus service to this pod whilst disabling DevServices to avoid Docker.